# Pass Php Arrays to External Javascript File

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I've seen some of the questions about the passing PHP arrays to an external JavaScript file, but I can't understand it. I know how to pass PHP arrays to internal JavaScript files but not how to pass them to external JavaScript files.

Coding

```
   <?php 
      $a = array("Apple","Orange","Grape");
   ?> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
      for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
          alert(jArray[i]);
      }
```

Comment: Use ajax to get variables from PHP

Comment: Not possible to use javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code,
**JS File (test.js)**

```
for(var i=0;i<jArray.length;i++){
alert(jArray[i]);
}
```

**PHP File (test.php)**

```
<?php 
      $a = array("Apple","Orange","Grape");
?>
<script type="text/javascript">var jArray =<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You cant use php code directly in your external `js` file, the given code is,

```
    <?php 
          $a = array("Apple","Orange","Grape");
    ?> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
      for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
          alert(jArray[i]);
      } 
  </script>

I think you can change the code as, 

   //Declaring the array in php 
   <?php 
      $a = array("Apple","Orange","Grape");
   ?> 

  //Assigning the json encoded format to javascript
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;  
  </script>

  //You can use the jArray in the external js file 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="externaljsfile.js" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass datas to external javascript file like you do to internals.

But, a solution can be :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // here you retrieve datas from PHP and use them as global from your external
    var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='externalJavascript.js'></script>
```

Else, a different solution could be getting datas with an AJAX request from your external file.